# Sequelize: how to spy on hooks with Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sequelize.js

I would like to be able to mock hooks on Sequelize objects but nothing seems to work for me.

In this particular instance, I want to mock `afterSave`

```js
// models/user.js
class User extends Model {
    ... 
    {
        hooks: {
            afterSave: async (user) => {
                return notifyAdmin(message, user)
            }
        }
    }
}

// service.js
module.exports.create = async data => {
    await user.create(data)
    return 'yay'
}
```

```js
// user.test.js
const user = require('models/user')

it('test', async () => {
    const mockSave = jest.spyOn(user.prototype, 'save')
    const mockHook = jest.spyOn(user.prototype, 'afterSave')

    await service.create({ first: 'han', last: 'solo' })
    expect(u.id).toBeDefined()
    expect(mockHook).toBeCalled()
})
```

This is a very contrived example but it does showcase what I want to do. That is to mock the `afterSave` hook; this doesn't work and throws an exception.

Reason for trying to do this is because most of our unit tests don't care if the notif functions are called (that gets tested somewhere else) but get bogged down by a hook.

One test I have goes from 20ms to 4s when the hook is enabled.

Hopefully, this question made some sense and someone can let me know what I'm doing wrong.